# "risk of cancer" or "cancer risk"?

Tags: word-choice

I would like to know if I should use "risk of cancer" or "cancer risk" is sentences such as the following (I've seen both of these "risk terms" being used in academic writing):

> 1. Smoking is associated with greater risk of cancer.
> 2. Smoking is associated with greater cancer risk.

Comment: You may use which ever you prefer. Both are common in English.

Comment: In half of one year, you merely asked 3 questions, but all involved "risk of cancer"... :D

Answer (score 1):

> Smoking is associated with greater risk of cancer.
>   Smoking is associated with greater cancer risk.

The word "greater" implies a comparison. Therefore, hopefully, these sentences are embedded in a context where you are comparing smoking with other risk-associated activities.

"Both working in the Chernobyl Exclusion Zone, and smoking, are dangerous activities. However, smoking is associated with (a) greater risk of cancer."

Adding the article "a" could be advisable. Other than that, both phrases should be alright.

Answer (score 1):

They are generally synonymous but you could use one or the other depending on which aspect, the risk or the cancer, you would like the reader to focus on.

> Flying has a very small risk....of cancer.

emphasizes the small risk, in this case of cancer.

> Skydiving has a very small cancer risk.

emphasizes that cancer is not common to skydiving, but other risks may be.

Answer (score 1):

From the examples of the usage presented in the Google Books, I've drawn a conclusion that both "greater risk of cancer" and  "greater cancer risk" in similar contexts are used interchangeably, with or without the "a" article. Yet—what may matter-- the usage frequency of the former is [almost three times higher](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=greater+risk+of+cancer%2Cgreater+cancer+risk&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgreater%20risk%20of%20cancer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreater%20cancer%20risk%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgreater%20risk%20of%20cancer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreater%20cancer%20risk%3B%2Cc0) than that of the latter. In my opinion, even if there are any distinctions to be made between them, they are too small and overfine to be of any, much less vital importance to a learner.